# Internet Explorer11 working too slow with protractor

Tags: angularjs, node.js, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I need to run my test cases in internet explorer 11 using protractor.When I execute test case,s it is consume much time when compare to Firefox and Chrome.
Even to enter the "Hello" text in text box it is taking 20 secs approximately.

Is there anyway to increase the execution speed in internet explorer 11?

**Following are my protractor details:**

- Selenium standalone server-2.47.1
- Node JS-0.12.7
- IE driverversion-IEDriverServer_x64_2.45.0

Please provide the details and links if we have something to increase the speed.
Thanks much.

Comment: simple solution is don't use IE *(always feels good saying that)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use x32 version of the driver. It may help.
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.47/

Comment: Could you please provide me the link to download x32 driver for IE11?

Comment: So, have it helped you?

Comment: Your are great man.It has worked fine.Thanks a lot for your help.